# No longer have permission to access my server: 403 error

Tags: html, permissions

I am a complete HTML novice and recently created a new index.html file for my personal website (the old site and index.html file was working fine). When I try to access my site, I get the following error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /user/www/ on this server.

The permissions on the /user/www/ folder are as follows:

> drwxr-xr-x  2 user nogroup 2048 Dec  5 04:03 www

and the permissions on the index.html file are:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 user nogroup 622 Dec  5 04:02 index.html

Any ideas what might have changed when I created the new index.html file that might be causing the problem?

Many thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Change your index.html file permission to 644 or 755.

Comment: Changing the permissions on index.html to 755 did not solve the problem...

Comment: Try creating a test file in the same folder, but create the file via your FTP client. See if that file can then load.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... First I will try and figure out how to create a file via my FTP client!

Comment: What FTP client are you using?